# MySQL Query with relations from article table to categories

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Database with the main table "articles" (artID, artName).

I also have a table with "categories" with the real titles and the id (catID, catTitle).

And then is there the between table "articles_categories" in which are the connecting ids (artID, catID) stored.

After some learning about MySQL ... I got at least the correct related rows.

BUT, it is possible that a article have more then 1 category.

The table articles_categories can have for example the rows:

```
artID,catID

0001,0100
0001,0105
0001,0120

0002,0104
0002,0120

0003,0110

0004,0205
0004,0250
0004,0401
```

And this is what I unfortunately get. I get for each article which is to more as to 1 category connected more then 1 row.

But I would like to have for each article only 1 row and the categories in a single field separated with semicolon.

This is what I get:

```
Article, Category
"apple", "fruit"
"apple", "food"
"pepsi","drink"
"pepsi","nonalcolic"
"pepsi","softdrink"
"chair","wood"
"chair","furniture"
"chair","kitchen"
```

But this what I want to get:

```
Article, Category
"apple", "fruit, food"
"pepsi","drink, nonalcolic, softdrink"
"chair","wood, furniture, kitchen"
```

---

Here is my SQL QUERY:

```
 SELECT a . * , ac . * , c . *
 FROM articles a, articlescategories ac, categories c
 WHERE a.artID = ac.artID AND ac.catID = c.catID
```

Comment: can you please give me some sample data for articles and category table in sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group_concat

```
SELECT a . * , GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name)
 FROM articles a, articlescategories ac, categories c
 WHERE a.artID = ac.artID AND ac.catID = c.catID
GROUP BY a.artID
```

**category_name** is your category name. You have to change this with your category name